# Dumping Subversion Repository one revision at a time

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump, svn-administraton

We have a big, giant sloppy Subversion repository that contains 60+ projects. The `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags` directories are in the root of the repository. Some branches are done `branches/project/branchName`. Others are done `branches/BranchName/project`. There's a lot of cruft.

There are almost 200,000 revisions, 22Gb, and 60+ projects.

I want to restructure the repository, so each project has its own repository, and institute standard branching strategy. Dumping the entire repository takes about 7 to 8 hours, and then filtering out what I want is a very long process since I have to run `svndumpfilter` multiple times.

I am thinking of a new strategy. If I look at the revisions involved in a single project, we might be talking about 400 revisions. I know I can run `svnadmin dump` on a range of revisions. What if I dump out just the revisions of the project I'm interested in? I can run `svnadmin dump` for each revision. I think this might actually be faster. However, how will this affect the load into a new repository?

Is there a problem of simply dumping only the revisions I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem that comes to my mind is that you wouldn't be able to load your new dumps straight to the new repos, because those dumps would be missing nodes to create parent folders (*trunk/branches/tags*, whatever) and `svnadmin load` command will fail with `File not found` error. So you will have to create them beforehand, like this: `svn mkdir http://server/svn/ProjectX/Trunk -m "Created Trunk"`

On the second thought, there could be all sorts of other issues if commits to your project have cross-references. E.g. you dump revisions from 1000 to 1500 for `/branches/ProjectX/branch`, but some node in dump will contain `Node-copyfrom-rev: 800` and `Node-copyfrom-path: /branches/ProjectY/branch` headers, because developer just wanted some shared file from that project and used the `svn copy` command. And here a filtering madness will begin. To mitigate that, you might try to process those dumps with [svndumpfilterIN](https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN) script, that will pull for you missing files from the live repo with `svnlook`. But beware, that it has it's own bugs (see my answer to this question: [SVNDumpFilter changing paths before adding them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889480/svndumpfilter-changing-paths-before-adding-them)).

On the third thought, if you want separate repos for each project, you'll probably also want to relocate dumped projects to the root folder and that is where things get real messy. For example, almost none of the known to me tools that able to relocate path in dumps such as [Svn-DumpReloc](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc), [svndumpsanitizer](https://github.com/dsuni/svndumpsanitizer) (not sure about [svndumptool](https://github.com/jwiegley/svndumptool) with merge hack) process `svn:mergeinfo` properties and that **will** cause your dump import to fail.

So, given your constraints, I can't see a solution using partial dumps, that wouldn't require some manual tinkering with repos and dump files afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, I gave up on this approach and simply kept the big bulky repo. The amount of possible gain just didn't match the amount of work it'll take. I'll give you the credit for an answer. You're the first person who responded in a year and a half.

Comment: Thanks @DavidW.  I'm on the warpath now, ripping projects from the huge SVN repo and converting them to Git. And there is sooo much left unmentioned in the popular tutorials, that I had to to share my experience with the world. And your question came in handy.