# SVNDumpFilter changing paths before adding them?

Tags: svn, svndump, svndumpfilter

I'm using `svndumpfilter` to extract single projects from a larger repo and import them into their own repo. Something like this:

```
svndumpfilter include --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs Trunk/Source/Project1 < full.dump > Project1.dump
```

It worked okay with one project, but on the second one, I notice that the resulting filtered dump does not start by adding a path. See the first two revisions (renumbered):

```
SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2

UUID: c6612063-4e6b-459c-a579-78605fb1e4b5

Revision-number: 0
Prop-content-length: 56
Content-length: 56

K 8
svn:date
V 27
2010-05-11T20:45:07.903005Z
PROPS-END

Revision-number: 1
Prop-content-length: 128
Content-length: 128

K 7
svn:log
V 27
Fixed code after branching.
K 10
svn:author
V 6
somedude
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2010-09-21T23:07:51.719341Z
PROPS-END

Node-path: Trunk/Source/Project1/Project1.csproj
Text-content-md5: 9d127596909e2a9921f1ec1c0223e1ed
Node-action: change
Text-content-sha1: 22eb675e0a5bfb41092de6ed39dc7c4d2a15dbd5
Node-kind: file
Text-content-length: 5178
Content-length: 5178
```

Notice how it is trying to "change" `Trunk/Source/Project1/Project1.csproj` before it ever added it in the first place? Not surprisingly, I get "file not found" when running `svnadmin load` on the filtered dump. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways:

1. Add missing folder via commit before loading dump file: `svn mkdir http://server/svn/project/Trunk -m "Created Trunk"`
2. Manually add a node record that creates `Trunk` folder to the dump:

   ```
   Revision-number: 1
   Prop-content-length: 128
   Content-length: 128

   K 7
   svn:log
   V 27
   Fixed code after branching.
   K 10
   svn:author
   V 6
   somedude
   K 8
   svn:date
   V 27
   2010-09-21T23:07:51.719341Z
   PROPS-END

   Node-path: Trunk/
   Node-kind: dir
   Node-action: add
   Prop-content-length: 48
   Content-length: 48

   PROPS-END


   Node-path: Trunk/Source/Project1/Project1.csproj
   Text-content-md5: 9d127596909e2a9921f1ec1c0223e1ed
   Node-action: change
   Text-content-sha1: 22eb675e0a5bfb41092de6ed39dc7c4d2a15dbd5
   Node-kind: file
   Text-content-length: 5178
   Content-length: 5178
   ```
3. Don't use `svndumpfilter` at all, because it's broken by design (*svndumpsanitizer*'s [home page](http://miria.homelinuxserver.org/svndumpsanitizer) has a good explanation why). There is a good chance, that you will encounter other errors further in your dump.

I'm currently in a process of splitting a devilishly complex repo with a lot of merges, moves and other such things and I can say that there is nothing around that handles splitting svn dumps 100% properly.

For example well-known [svndumpfilterIN](https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN) contains at least three major bugs (I've only managed to report [one of them](https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN/issues/7) and other two are much more evil) and failed miserably on my repo. I'll try to share a fixed version of it on GitHub some time later, but in it's current state I can't recommend it.

So in my opinion, your best chance is to try abovementioned [svndumpsanitizer](https://github.com/dsuni/svndumpsanitizer) without `--redefine-root` option, because it's bugged too (bugreport coming). If you're on Windows, it compiles fine with the latest [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) (free).

---

## Updated in Y2K17

The last two paragraphs above are no longer relevant, since I've fixed all the issues in the [svndumpfilterIN](https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN), that were stopping me from converting my repo. [My PR](https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN/pull/8) has been merged to the base repo, so give it a try. I still can't guarantee 100% success, but your chances are much higher now.

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember exactly how I fixed this but I think I ended up manually editing the file and adding missing files/folders where needed.